# Compiling and running an application from Processing using SimpleOpenNI library fails to load on MacOSx

Tags: executable, processing, openni, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Has anyone successfully used the processing simpleOPENNI library and exported a processing application that runs ? (on a mac)

I have a mac osx 10.8 and I am using SimpleOpenNI library that is giving trouble when compiling an application. When just running the processing sketch, it runs no problem. But it won't work with a compiled app. How can I run a compiled application for a Mac using the SimpleOpenNI library???

This is similar to this forum but the solution presented here is not working for my problem on a mac :https://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/issues/detail?id=73

This happens when I Compile application with proccessing then run the application. The processing sketch works fine.

The Application fails to load openni libs with error:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
SimpleOpenNI.SimpleOp at SimpleOpenNI.SimpleOpenNiJNI.swig_module_init(Native Method) 
at SimpleOpenNI.SimpleOpenNIJNI.(SimpleOpenNIJNI.java:290) at 
SimpleOpenNI.ContextWrapper.(ContextWrapper.java:54) at SimpleOpenNI.SimpleOpenNI.
(SimpleOpenNi.java:256) at LanScapesLerp.setup(LanScapesLerp.java:126) at 
processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:1530) at 
processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:1608) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: If you open up your exported `.app` (Show Package Contents) and look inside for the jars/.so files, do you see the OpenNi `.so` library file?  I'm wondering if it isn't being added to the package -- or if it simply isn't being added to the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the library a different way, such as downloading it from a website (https://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/) this has seemed to work for most people with java.lang.UnsatasfiedLinkError

Comment: I've tried this and every variation I could think of, and it hasn't worked. There are only two ways to install Simple-OpenNI: unzip the file from the website in your Processing/Libraries directory or use the built-in Add Libraries feature in Processing 2.0. Open to any other suggestions!

Comment: @JaredH - yea I agree - sure I tried both ways. And yes it was from that website https://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/

Comment: @TheDoctor: you wrote : "this has seemed to work for most people"... with this error? The processing simple open NI sketch is working but the application when I export it is not. 

Any more insight?